# Using multiple "and" and "comma" in one sentence

Tags: commas, syntactic-analysis, conjunctions

I'm trying to write an "About Us" page of a blog, where I'm facing issue of using multiple *and*s and commas. I don't know if it's correct grammar or not. Can I use the following sentence? Is it correct?

> We analyze, review, compare and discuss the latest trends, releases and popular topics.

Use of multiple ***and*s**  here seems a bit odd to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not "multiple" *and*s -- they appear in separate clauses -- that's fine by grammar.

Parse it this way:

> We (analyze, review, compare and discuss) the (latest trends, releases and popular topics.)

HTH.

Comment: I'd call it a single clause with multiple verbs and multiple nouns. (Although, from a "conceptual" point of view, I suppose you could could argue it's the concatenation of twelve separate clauses—but I don't think it can normally be analyzed that way.) However, how you parsed it is definitely useful.

Comment: @JasonBassford Oh yes, verb-phrase, noun-phrase, rather, not clauses.